# Copy files in one folder to another

Tags: java

The title is a little misleading, so I'll elaborate here: I have a directory, and in it is a lot of subdirectories, with files in those. I want to be able to copy all the files over to another directory, but not the folders.

This is what I want done:

Before:

```
Directory from
    folder a
         folder b
              something.txt
              folder c
                  somethingelse.txt
    folder c
         anotherthing.txt
```

After:

```
Directory to
    something.txt
    somethingelse.txt
    anotherthing.txt
```

I would prefer not to use any external libraries.

Comment: Consider looking into [Apache Commons FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels It's a small project, so I don't want to have to add a huge library

Comment: Ahahaha. A single Commons component isn't a "huge library". "Small" Java projects routinely grab a hundred or more.

Comment: I thought you had to add the whole library

Comment: Have a look at [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) and [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 7 there is a new API for the filesystem. You may use a [FileWalker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)
to collect a reference to all the FILES (not directories) and then simply copy them over using the same API. With the [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) of each file you will be able to get the name of the file without keeping the rest of the path. Simmilar to `getFileName()` from File.